# iOS: incompatibile block pointer types

Tags: ipad, ios, objective-c-blocks

This code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f animations:^() {
 self.view.alpha = 1.0f;
}];
```

is generating this compile time error:

> Incompatible block pointer types initializing 'void (^)()', expected 'void (^)(void)'

What gives -- this has worked previously (and in fact compiles in other project just fine -- (I just checked).  Is there a compiler/project setting that I've overlooked?

Base SDK is 4.2, deployment target is 4.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try declaring it as `[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f animations:^{ self.view.alpha = 1.0f; }];`

The `()` is optional with no params, and may be confusing the parser. Which compiler are you using? I'd recommend LLVM, 1.6 I think is the latest version in XCode.

Comment: Thanks -- changed to the LLVM compiler and it compiles (and runs)

Comment: And removing the () and using gcc works just fine too.  Thanks again.

Comment: I'd still say use LLVM whenever possible (always)

Comment: Thanks I had an unrelated blocks issue and changing the compiler to LLVM fixed this. +1

Comment: I changed to Apple LLVM compiler 3.1 (default) now works fine +1